# Selection of large number of rows from PostgreSql using python is very slow

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute a select query using python , which has over 200,000 results/rows. The same query which outputs 200,000 rows takes around 10-15 secs on the DB_ENGINE(Dbeaver) but while trying to execute it using python, it takes around 6 minutes. I am using psycopg2, SQLALCHEMY engine.

```
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, poolclass=NullPool)
conn = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

Can anyone suggest ways to optimise it to the level of Dbeaver output's time.

Other ways tried:

- Part 1:

  ```
   df = pd.DataFrame()  
   dfl = []
   for chunk in pd.read_sql_query( query, con=engine ,chunksize=5000):
     print('chunk from PSQL', chunk)
   # Start Appending Data Chunks from PSQL Result set into List
     dfl.append(chunk)
   # Start appending data from list to dataframe
     df = pd.concat(dfl, ignore_index=True)
  ```

Part 2:

```
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
        copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
            query=query, head="HEADER"
        )
        conn = engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpfile)
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_csv(tmpfile)
        tmpfile.close()
```

Comment: For"part.2" how much time was spent at each step?

Comment: Does dbeaver even read the output, or does it read N rows only and stop?

Comment: @jjanes for part 2, the timing was still a lot after copy_expert, wasnt much of an improvement or any at all. And yes , u r right, Dbeaver reads only few rows

Comment: @jjanescan u suggest ways on fetching over 200,000 rows in a quicker way using py

Comment: How long does the query take when run with EXPLAIN ANALYZE?